# How you calculate this double integral

Tags: integration

$$I = \iint_D f(x,y)\,dx\,dy\:$$ $D=[a,b]\times[c,d]$ and $f(x,y) = g(x)\times h(y)$

Comment: It is seperable, you can turn it into a product of two integrals each of their own variable.

Comment: Ever heard of Fubini?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since $ f(x,y) = g(x) \times h(y) $, you can separate the double integral into two integrals, i.e.

$$ \int \int_{D} f(x,y) dx dy = \int \int_{D} g(x) h(y) dx dy = \int_{c}^{d} \int_{a}^{b} g(x) h(y) dx dy = \int_{c}^{d} h(y)dy \int_{a}^{b} g(x)dx $$

Comment: "You can", if...